# EWS (java API): how to resolve a name which is "hidden in address list"?

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I'm using [ews-java-api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) to access Exchange servers.

I use `resolveName(useraddress)` to check user existence and to get some user informations (like its name, etc.).

But when that user is marked as *hidden in address list*, `resolveName` returns `null`.

Is there a way to retrieve *hidden in address list* users using EWS ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the 'feature' of hidden for addresslists means that address isn't discoverable by any of the Mail API's. If you want to find that information you need to use a Directory API and access it directly eg for onPrem use LDAP or for Office365 use the Graph API.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's obviously not the answer I was expecting, but I'll have to live with that.